# Why does variance divide by $n-1$?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics

> The variance is: $$\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar x)^2}{n-1}$$

I read that $n-1$ is used instead of just $n$ when we are measuring the variance of a sample taken from a bigger population. I don't understand why we're subtracting $1$.

Thank you.

Comment: This question was asked a few days ago.

Comment: I'm asking why you're dividing by $n-1$, not squaring it, how are they the same questions? @SanathDevalapurkar

Answer (score 0):

A similar way of saying it.  Divide by $n$ to compute the variance of your random sample.  Divide by $n-1$ to use your sample to compute an estimate for the variance of the population.